# SQL Server DATEDIFF: How's dayofyear different from day?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When I look at the [DATEDIFF()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794) function on SQL Server, I see that it takes a *datepart* as its first parameter.

Possible *datepart* values include *day* and *dayofyear*.

I understand that *dayofyear* is the day number of the year (so that Feb 2 is 33, for example) and *day* is the day of the month (so that Feb 2 is 2).  However, I don't understand the difference when it comes to the DATEDIFF function.

Here are some examples:

```
select DATEDIFF(dayofyear, '2012-01-01', '2012-02-02')
returns: 32

select DATEDIFF(day, '2012-01-01', '2012-02-02')
returns: 32

select DATEDIFF(dayofyear, '2011-02-01', '2012-02-02')
returns: 366

select DATEDIFF(day, '2011-02-01', '2012-02-02')
returns 366
```

Are *dayofyear* and *day* equivalent for the purposes of DATEDIFF()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is the same effect for `DATEDIFF()`.  For an arithmatetic function like `DATEDIFF()`, it will have the same result, as the math is still taking into account the same unit: whether it's for `day` or `dayofyear` they are both still in days.